# Adding a value to a template name

Tags: xslt

I have the following declarations:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ad_state800x100"><xsl:with-param name="state" select="/*/locations/@state" /></xsl:call-template>
```

And for the xpos

```
<xsl:variable name="xpos" select="substring-before(position(),'0')" />
```

What I want is the following:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ad$xpos_state800x100">
```

So if the position is 10, it will be:

```
<xsl:call-template name="ad1_state800x100">
```

How do I achieve this

Comment: That's not possible: the `name` attribute of `xsl:call-template` cannot be calculated at runtime. Ask about your [real problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a dynamic decision which of several templates to invoke, the correct XSLT mechanism for doing that is xsl:apply-templates.

You haven't told us enough about your problem for me to know exactly how you would do this in your case, or indeed whether dynamic despatch needs to be part of the solution at all. In fact, you haven't told us anything about your problem - only an attempt at a solution that won't work.